# SQL Server 2014 Triggers and where are they created

Tags: sql-server

I am on SQL Server 2014 Standard edition. I am developing a Supply Chain DW and I am currently in the process of building a Landing schema which will be used to Land data coming out of the source system and then move that data into a Staging schema to begin the ETL process. I am truncating the landing tables after I have moved that days data into Staging. I am using Hashbytes in a Trigger which will add a hash value to each record for comparison while being moved upstream.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgr_hashval_mara ON land.mara
FOR UPDATE, INSERT AS
UPDATE land.mara
SET HashVal = (SELECT hashbytes('md5', (SELECT material, MaterialDesc FOR xml raw)));
```

I can create these all day long, but I am unable to Drop them using conventional syntax as below. Executing the DROP statement produces an error.

```
 DROP TRIGGER trgr_hashval_mara;
```

`"Can't find trigger or you don't have permission to drop trigger."`

However the following statement comes back with a list of Triggers I have created.

```
select * from ibscm01.sys.triggers
```

I also can't seem to find them in the DB Tree. I see the Database Triggers child, but there are no Items/triggers shown. I am using Toad for SQL server 6.7 which should be the current release. also using Windows Authentication with AD and I have dbo privileges.

[image]

Thanks,
Pat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Triggers will be in the same Schema as the Table that they are created on. This is either handled automatically if the Schema is not specified in the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, or it is enforced if it is specified but not the same as the Schema of the Table. The MSDN documentation for [CREATE TRIGGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) states:

> DML triggers are scoped to the schema of the table or view on which they are created.

And a simple test confirms the enforcement of this rule:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [TriggerTest];
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TriggerSchemaTest (Col1 INT);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [TriggerTest].[DifferentSchemaThanTable]
ON [dbo].[TriggerSchemaTest]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @DoNothing INT;
END;
GO
```

produces the following error:

> Msg 2103, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DifferentSchemaThanTable, Line 6
>   Cannot create trigger 'TriggerTest.DifferentSchemaThanTable' because its schema is different from the schema of the target table or view.

---

The syntax for dropping a Trigger, according to the SQL Server 2012 & 2014 MSDN page for [DROP TRIGGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173497(v=sql.110).aspx), is (essentially):

```
DROP TRIGGER [schema_name.]trigger_name;
```

So, if you want to know what Schema a particular Trigger (and its parent Table) is in, use the following query:

```
SELECT ss.[name] AS [TableAndTriggerSchemaName],
       so.[name] AS [TriggerName],
       st.[name] AS [TableName]
FROM   sys.objects so
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ss
        ON ss.[schema_id] = so.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.tables st
        ON st.[object_id] = so.[parent_object_id]
WHERE  so.[name] = N'trgr_hashval_mara';
```

Also:

- This is one reason (readability) why it is best to always specify the Schema name when creating Schema-bound objects (rather than relying upon default behavior). Hence you should be using: `CREATE TRIGGER land.trgr_hashval_mara ON land.mara...`
- If that is your entire, actual Trigger code, there is a huge problem: it is updating all rows of the table for each and every `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statement. Is that really what is desired? You need to be joining to the `INSERTED` pseudo-table so that you only update rows that are actually changing.
- You might want to add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the top of each Trigger.